# Bass.dll not finding basswasapi.dll

Tags: c#, bass, bass.dll

I've just downloaded this [code][1] of a Spectrum Analyzer in C# using the BASS API. I downloaded the Dll, added to the solution, but when I try to run the project, it says that it couldn't find the DLL basswasapi. I tried to search on the internet to download this file, but all of them that I found, when a put in the project's file, it shows up a new error saying that it couldn't find an entry point called BASS_WASAPI_GetCPU. I'm running now with Windows 10, I don't know if it has anything to do with the errors. If any of you guys could send me the basswasapi dll or just tell me where I can find it, I would really appreciate that.

Thanks.

The code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797537/Making-an-Audio-Spectrum-analyzer-with-Bass-dll-Cs

Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhKA0.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I fixed it. A guy in the BASS forum helped me out. I was just forgeting to download the bass.dll file.